# Capturing a programs performance

Tags: directx, performance

I'm trying to capture the performance of the GPU, CPU, FPS and memory usage on a program I'm currently working with and want to avoid having to write my own performance capture stuff. Does anyone know of a good program/programs that can do 1 or more of the above?

Ideally something that is simple to use. I've googled a few, but getting them to work has been a right pain. The couple that I've tried out have given me my entire systems performance, as opposed to just my running program.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm currently using DirectX 9 and C++ for my program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an NVidia card, maybe take a look at [PerfHUD](http://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-perfhud). It's a bit complicated at first, but you can start by ignoring the advanced stuff if you want.
It requires instrumenting your application (during device creation), but when I did it for our legacy 3D application at my previous job, it was just copy/pasting the example given by NVidia without any problem. And it gave me really valuable informations.

It's only for the GPU, for the CPU I used [AMD CodeAnalyst](http://developer.amd.com/tools/CodeAnalyst/Pages/default.aspx) (haven't tried the Intel equivalent, VTune, which isn't free). Quite simple to use and did a good job helping me to find bottlenecks.